# javascript validation to check if input is empty,by getting the element id

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and trying some code..
 for validation in javascript I tried the below code and it works

```
<input id="idd" type="number" min="400" max="500">
<button onclick="myFunction()">OK</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
 var inobj = document.getElementById("idd"); 
      //to check if input is between 400 to 500 
 if (inobj.checkValidity() == false)
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = inobj.validationMessage;
    }

// to check if  input is empty
else if(inobj.value ==""||inobj.value==NULL)                                
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="enter input";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Input OK";
     } 
    } 
    </script>
```

when I try to use the below code to check if  input is empty
it does not work .why does this happen?

```
// to check if  input is empty

var y = inobj.value;
else if( y == ""||y == NULL)                                
{
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="enter input";
}
```

Can't we assign inobj.value to y and then use it in the else if condition.

Comment: Are you getting any parse errors?

Comment: You don't really have `var y = inobj.value;` between `else if`, do you?

Comment: can you post your entrie if statment?... you can´t set a var before the ´else if´

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're defining your y variable outside of the scope where it's used, so when you try to compare it y is evaluated as undefined.

make your

```
var y = inojb.value
```

just below the

```
var inobj = document.getElementById("idd");
```

line, and it should work

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it right just before the else if. The only thing you have to have before the else if is the **closing brace of the previous if**.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you initializing `var y`? Are you doing it in the `if(){}` clause and then trying to use it in the `else if(){}` clause? If so, you have to initialize it before the clauses, otherwise it is never initialized when you go to check the value.

```
<input id="idd" type="number" min="400" max="500">
<button onclick="myFunction()">OK</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
 var inobj = document.getElementById("idd");    
 var y = inobj.value;
                        //to check if input is between 400 to 500



 if (inobj.checkValidity() == false)
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = inobj.validationMessage;
    }

// to check if  input is empty
else if(y == ""||y == NULL)                                
    {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="enter input";
    }
    else 
    {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Input OK";
        } 
    } 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
 var inobj = document.getElementById("idd"); 
 var y = inojb.value
 
 //to check if input is between 400 to 500 
 if (inobj.checkValidity() == false)
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = inobj.validationMessage;
    }

// to check if  input is empty
else if(y == "" | y == null)                                
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="enter input";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Input OK";
     } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is because you try to declare a variable between the `if` block and the `else` block. Just declare your variable outside the `if` block.